# Apache mod_rewrite: remove only a specific folder from the url and remove the extension from all the files inside that folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I've tried some different solutions I've found on the web on my .htaccess file (placed in the root of my website), but I always end up with an "Internal Server Error"...

I need a generic rule to remove a specific folder from the URL and the extension of all the files contained in it (adding a trailing slash at the end), with a redirection to the rewrited url. So, for example:

the folder I want to work on is called "pages", so the rule should not affect any other folder, and I want that the url

```
http://www.example.com/subfolder/pages/
will be rewrited/redirected to
http://www.example.com/subfolder/
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/subfolder/pages/page1.php
will be rewrited/redirected to
http://www.example.com/subfolder/page1/
```

and

```
http://www.example.com/subfolder/pages/subpages/page1.php
will be rewrited/redirected to
http://www.example.com/subfolder/subpages/page1/
```

and so on...

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This would be more logical in 2 rules:

1. Remove extension: /subfolder/pages/(.*).[^.]+ -> /subfolder/pages/$1/
2. Remove pages from URL: /subfolder/pages/(.*) -> /subfolder/$1

Didn't test the rules but this should get you there.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it tonight and I'll let you know if I can manage to make it work ;)